# How does prob argument in rbinom work when prob is a vector?

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
rbinom(17, 1, .5)
```

This code denotes each observation has probability of success  equal to 0.5.

In `rbinom(3, 1, c(.5,.3,.7))`, the first observation has probability of success 0.5, the second observation has probability of success equal to 0.3, and the last observation has probability of success equal to 0.7.

But in

```
rbinom(17, 1, c(.5,.3,.7))
```

, how is the probability of success distributed among the 17 observation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vector is recycled over the 17 generated values:

```
> rbinom(17, 1, c(0,.999))
 [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Often R will generate a warning if you try recycling two vectors that aren't don't fit into each other:

```
> (1:10) + (1:3)
 [1]  2  4  6  5  7  9  8 10 12 11
Warning message:
In (1:10) + (1:3) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

but not in this case.