# Where is the code for recycling `rbinom` inputs?

Tags: c, r, cran

From the documentation, `rbinom` takes three arguments, `n`, `size`, and `prob`. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926683/how-does-prob-argument-in-rbinom-work-when-prob-is-a-vector) states that if `prob` is a vector, it is recycled until `n` is reached. I want to find that code!

The R source immediately calls a C function:

```
> rbinom
function (n, size, prob) 
.Call(C_rbinom, n, size, prob)
<bytecode: 0x113526220>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Searching the Github mirror for R [gets me the this `rbinom` C function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/rbinom.c#L45), but it only takes two arguments. Where is `n`? Where is the recycling of `prob` to the length of `n`? I can't find it in this function definition.

```
double rbinom(double nin, double pp)
{
...
}
```

Searching for [all C files containing `rbinom`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?l=C&q=rbinom), the only other relevant-seeming C file I found [is this one](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/stats/src/random.c#L153), but I don't understand it. Is this where the recycling happens, or is there another function definition somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: I've edited to drastically shorten the question and focus on your `rbinom` problem, since the "finding the C code" is addressed at the (former) duplicate. My C isn't good enough to answer after the code skim, but I think the answer has to do with "other relevant-seeming C file", which seems to do general processing for sampling from 2-parameter families before the `rbinom` you found is called.

Comment: Also, the dll bits are a distraction. When compiled for windows, the C code produces the DLL files you found. I'd advise searching the code on github rather than locally, it's a much nicer interface unless you've got a nice IDE and a lot of practice using it.

Comment: Thank you, with this help I might be able to sort it out my self. It's hard when you do not even know what to ask about.

Comment: Your second C file is the answer: the solution is a combination of the `random2` function you pointed to and the `DEFRAND2_INT` macro ...

Comment: And there it was. Line 185: ` rx = fn(ra[i % na], rb[i % nb]);` The solution came from you pointing me to the second file and me reading up on preprocessors (context-insensitive text replace). I'm still not confident enough to post an answer. Should I close the question, delte it or wait for someone who knows more C to give a good reply?

Comment: I recommend writing up your comment into a short answer---doesn't need to be much more than the comment. If no one else has answered within 24 hours, go ahead and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the helpful guidance of stack overflow I managed to answer this to my satisfaction. I'm not sure about the details, but here goes:

`> rbinom`

calls this line

`rbinom <- function(n, size, prob) .Call(C_rbinom, n, size, prob)`

located at line 149 of 
`/src/library/stats/R/distn.R`

This in turn is going to call

`static R_INLINE SEXP random2(SEXP sn, SEXP sa, SEXP sb, ran2 fn, SEXPTYPE type)`

with `sn=n`, `sa=size`, `sb=prob` and `fn=rbinom`.

In that function the code you want is on ine 185: `rx = fn(ra[i % na], rb[i % nb]);` which shows that rbinom is called recycling both the size and prob parameter.

The connection between random2 and rbinom is established with a preprocessor in the same file as the function random2.

```
DEFRAND2_INT(rbinom)
```

```
#define DEFRAND2_INT(name) \
    SEXP do_##name(SEXP sn, SEXP sa, SEXP sb) { \
        return random2(sn, sa, sb, name, INTSXP); \
    }
```